# ANDROID:How to format text that has to be saved in textfile

Tags: java, android

I have an app in which I can choose data from a database and then I show the result in a TableView. Next thing I want to do is save the chosen data (currently shown in the TableView) into a textfile, so it can copied onto a PC and printed out on to paper. What I'm trying to achieve is equal spaces between each column. I'm using something like this to save text to a file:

```
out.write("\n "+name+" \t"+amount+" \t"+price);
```

But after opening the file in a text editor it doesn't look good. Is this the right method to do it? If not what is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use function String.format to do that.

For example:

```
out.write ( String.format("%s %10d %10d", name, amount, price) );
```

This code will print name.toString() and then integers amount and price in fields with 10 characters width.

You can read about format strings [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: Thanks, That is what I'v been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Why not save your data in a HTML formatted file? Then you could build your table with the HTML table tags.

Or, since the report is to be printed to paper, you might want to try saving to the more printer friendly PDF format. I think there are several free/open source PDF writer libraries for Java. Perhaps some of them will work for Android too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have certain max length for column data (let it be static or calculated dynamically) you could do something like this;

```
String column = "                   "; // enough spaces for actual data.
out.write(name + column.substring(name.length));
etc..
```